# Is $1+1=x$ something related to Algebra or algebraic equation?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, definition

If algebra is a branch of mathematics dealing with **finding the unknown values or quantities**, then I can say something like  $1+1=x$ is an algebraic equation.

This kind of problems for sure is not related to algebra, it's all about normal computation, but I could write it this way because there is no certain rule prevents me from doing it, right?.

Is there any kind of rigorous definition to algebra that Distinguishes it from this Vague?

Comment: You might be looking for [Peano Arithmetic?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_axioms)

Comment: An *equation* is anything with an equal sign and two things either side of it. 1+1 = x *is* an equation. How is it *not* related to algebra?

Comment: You will find that your current definition of Algebra is quite limited if you come to study the subject at advanced levels. Solving equations is where you begin, and remains significant, but other properties of equations and numbers and number-like systems come into play as well - and then comes the possibility of translating problems in other fields like geometry and arithmetic into algebra where algebraic techniques provide insight ... (and more besides). It is quite a journey, and full of fascination and mathematical patterns and surprises.

Comment: @AdamRubinson This is normal computation rather than logical thinking, we did, between two sides to find something unknown.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by “logical thinking”, and what do you mean by “normal computation”?

Answer (score -1):

Algebra are arithmetic are essentially the same thing, and I think it is a shame that most teachers in schools act as if adding letters into equations is a huge leap from simple computation. When we first learn math, we are given problems like $$\text{What is }9-5\text{?}$$
However, this question could be asked as $$9-5=\text{?}$$
Or, $$9-5=x$$
As long as students understand the idea that if we apply equal operations to equal things, they stay equal, then algebraic manipulations like $$x+5=9$$ 
$$x=9-5$$
$$x=4$$
should feel very natural.

Comment: I think adding letters into equations _is_ a huge leap. I would not expect young students to find it natural.

Comment: $9-5=?$ is like "calculate $9-5$". But (properly) handling $x+5=9$ is like "understand that this means there is a number $x$ such that when $5$ is added to it, it is the same number as $9$, so to discover $x$ you can manipulate the two expressions in identical ways since they are the same number. Since subtraction undoes addition...". I agree with Tony that it is a huge leap here.

Comment: Fair enough then.